# Action after tweet has been published

Tags: ios, twitter, sprite-kit

I set a button in my game where you can tweet your score. The thing is that when the user just publishes the tweet I want to open a new view and I don't know how to know when the tweet has been published. For publish the tweet I used this code:

```
-(void)shareTwitter {
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I've just scored 98 points!];

    UIViewController *controller = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [controller presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a completion handler on your tweetSheet like so:

```
[tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

         switch (result) {
             case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                 NSLog(@"Post Canceled");
                 break;
             case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                 NSLog(@"Post Sucessful");
                 break;

             default:
                 break;
         }
     }];
```